# group by sum with Every Sum group ending last Rows using Sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, tradingview-api

I have Attached one Image and i want 7800-2000=5800 with based on under group last rows total sum using sql server query
[image]

i want output like this

```
GroupName     Credit    Debit   DrCrEffect  UnderGroupName  Total
Opening Balance 0.00    0.00    Dr         Master Group      NULL
Opening Stock   0.00    0.00    Dr         Opening Stock     NULL
Purchase        0.00    7800.00 Dr         Purchase          0.00 
Purchase Return 2000.00  0.00   Dr          Purchase         5800
```

Query:

```
SELECT MAG.GroupName,
    SUM(isnull(tm.Credit,0.00))Credit,
    SUM(ISNULL(TM.Debit,0.00))Debit,
    mag.DrCrEffect,
    MAG.UnderGroupName,
    SUM(TM.Credit-tm.Debit)Total
FROM dbo.Mst_Account_Group MAG
    LEFT JOIN  dbo.Party P ON MAG.Mst_Account_Group_Id = P.Mst_Account_Group_Id 
        AND mag.EffectTo='Trading Account' AND MAG.DrCrEffect='dr'
    LEFT JOIN  dbo.Transaction_Master TM ON tm.Ledger_Id=p.Party_Id
WHERE P.Company_Id=1 AND P.Branch_Id=1
GROUP BY mag.GroupName, mag.DrCrEffect, MAG.UnderGroupName
```

Comment: Dont use images - And i dont understand what you want? Can you write expected results?

Comment: thomas i want sum of every undergroupby with last rows i also attached screenshot you knows

Comment: @alpeshramani You didn't mention what's the problem you are facing? What's your expected result? Until then no one will be bale to help you.

Comment: But this will then be on every undergroup so you will have 5800 on all purchase undergroup -

Comment: Jibin Balachandran i want  sum of every undergroupby rows with last group rows as i red indicated

Comment: Can you post your sample data and the expected output?

Comment: Jibin Balachandran please referesh page and i updated first text output put in my question not image ,image is my query output

Comment: Please see i updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to achieve this. LAG will give you the value from previous row in the current row selection.

```
declare @table table (groupname varchar(50),
                      credit numeric(18,2),
                      debit numeric(18,2),
                      drcreffect varchar(50),
                      undergroup varchar(50))

insert into @table values
('Opening Balance', 0.00   , 0.00    ,'Dr',  'Master Group'   ),
('Opening Stock',   0.00   , 0.00    ,'Dr',  'Opening Stock' ),
('Purchase',        0.00   , 7800.00 ,'Dr',  'Purchase'),
('Purchase Return', 2000.00,  0.00   ,'Dr',  'Purchase')


select groupname,
       credit,
       debit,
       drcreffect,
       undergroup, 
       LAG(debit,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY groupname)-credit AS Total
from @table
```

**Output:**

[image: Output]

**Note:** Replace `@table` with your actual table name.

**Update:**

```
declare @table table (groupname varchar(50),
                      credit numeric(18,2),
                      debit numeric(18,2),
                      drcreffect varchar(50),
                      undergroup varchar(50))

insert into @table values
('Opening Balance', 0.00   , 0.00    ,'Dr',  'Master Group'   ),
('Opening Stock',   0.00   , 0.00    ,'Dr',  'Opening Stock' ),
('Purchase',        0.00   , 7800.00 ,'Dr',  'Purchase'),
('Purchase Return', 2000.00,  0.00   ,'Dr',  'Purchase'),
('Purchase Return', 3000.00, 0.00 ,'Dr', 'Purchase'),
('Sales', 0.00, 5000.00 ,'Dr', 'Sales'),
('Sales Return', 2000.00,  0.00   ,'Dr',  'Sales'),
('Sales Return', 2000.00, 0.00 ,'Dr', 'Sales')


SELECT groupname,credit,debit,drcreffect,undergroup, LAG(debit,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY groupname)-credit AS Total from (
SELECT DISTINCT groupname,SUM(credit) OVER(PARTITION BY groupname) AS Credit,SUM(debit) OVER(PARTITION BY groupname) AS debit,drcreffect,undergroup
FROM @table ) X
```

Comment: insert into @table values
('Opening Balance', 0.00   , 0.00    ,'Dr',  'Master Group'   ),
('Opening Stock',   0.00   , 0.00    ,'Dr',  'Opening Stock' ),
('Purchase',        0.00   , 7800.00 ,'Dr',  'Purchase'),
('Purchase Return', 2000.00,  0.00   ,'Dr',  'Purchase'),
('Purchase Return', 2000.00,  0.00   ,'Dr',  'Purchase')

Please add  this result and check  your logic is right.but one more purchase return add 2000 and result is 3800 but issue some logic

Comment: yes query is ready but one more purchase return add so 5800 and purchase return 2000 again so output 5800 insted of 3800 final value but not please help me

Comment: add again ('Purchase Return', 3000.00,  0.00   ,'Dr',  'Purchase')
and now  value (7800-2000-3000) final sum  group by =2800

Comment: If you add `('Purchase Return', 3000.00, 0.00 ,'Dr', 'Purchase')`, you will get `-3000.00` as total for that row i.e  `0.00 - 3000.00= -3000.00`  (debit of previous row - credit)

Comment: I attached full example with add new return with one more group 
groupname credit debit drcreffect undergroup Total
Opening Balance 0.00 0.00 Dr  Master Group 0.00
Opening Stock 0.00 0.00 Dr  Opening Stock 0.00
Purchase 0.00 7800.00 Dr  Purchase 0.00
Purchase Return 2000.00 0.00 Dr  Purchase 0.00
Purchase Return 3000.00 0.00 Dr  Purchase 2800.00
Sales  0.00 5000.00 Dr  Sales  0.00
sales  Return 2000.00 0.00 Dr  sales  0.00
sales  Return 2000.00 0.00 Dr  sales  1000.00

Comment: @alpeshramani Update your expected output. I can't understand anything from this comment.

Comment: http://www.aramani.in/a.png

see image i want group by sum (credit-debit) and add total sum in last groupby rows

Comment: @alpeshramani Updated my answer, have a look and let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: thanks Jibin Balachandran you are Great.
can you help me your output 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51019762/i-want-2-table-to-merge-and-convert-into-1-table-using-sql-server

Comment: no  Jibin Balachandran  some this different output table is your last answer but i want add some output images please see

Comment: thanks please check my updated and formated question i thing you understand better
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51019762/i-want-2-table-to-merge-and-convert-into-1-table-using-sql-server
:)

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210933/group-by-sum-based-on-under-group-in-sql-server
Please check my update question i thing easily understand ,everything is coverd but some miner bugs issues