# I want 2 tables to merge and convert into 1 table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @table table (groupname varchar(50),
                      credit numeric(18,2),
                      debit numeric(18,2),
                      drcreffect varchar(50),
                      undergroup varchar(50)
                     )

declare @table1 table (groupname varchar(50),
                       credit numeric(18,2),
                       debit numeric(18,2),
                       drcreffect varchar(50),
                       undergroup varchar(50)
                      )

insert into @table 
values ('Opening Balance', 0.00, 0.00, 'Dr', 'Master Group'),
       ('Opening Stock',   0.00, 0.00, 'Dr', 'Opening Stock'),
       ('Purchase',        0.00, 7800.00, 'Dr', 'Purchase'),
       ('Purchase Return', 2000.00, 0.00, 'Dr', 'Purchase'),
       ('Purchase Return', 3000.00, 0.00, 'Dr', 'Purchase'),
       ('Purchase Return', 3000.00, 0.00, 'Dr', 'Purchase')

insert into @table1 
values ('Sales', 0.00, 5000.00 ,'Dr', 'Sales'),
       ('Sales Return', 2000.00, 0.00,'Dr', 'Sales'),
       ('Sales Return', 2000.00, 0.00,'Dr', 'Sales')

SELECT 
    groupname, credit, debit, 
    LAG(debit,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY groupname) - credit AS Total 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         groupname, 
         SUM(credit) OVER (PARTITION BY groupname) AS Credit,
         SUM(debit) OVER (PARTITION BY groupname) AS debit,
         drcreffect, undergroup
     FROM 
         @table) X

SELECT 
    groupname, credit, debit, 
    LAG(debit, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY groupname) - credit AS Total 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         groupname,
         SUM(credit) OVER(PARTITION BY groupname) AS Credit,
         SUM(debit) OVER(PARTITION BY groupname) AS debit,
         drcreffect, undergroup
     FROM 
         @table1) X
```

Here is 2 table if run above script

[image]

I want output like merge 2 table and output like below images

[image]

Comment: First of all you cant have the same columnnames multiple times, and why do you want to merge them ?

Comment: you can change name as you confirtable but output main foucus

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables using the row number. Should work something like this:

```
select t0.groupname, t0.credit, t0.debit, t0.Total ,t1.groupname as groupname1 , t1.credit as credit1, t1.debit as debit, t1.Total as Total1

from(
    SELECT row_number() as row_num, groupname,credit,debit, LAG(debit,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY groupname)-credit AS Total from (
        SELECT DISTINCT groupname,SUM(credit) OVER(PARTITION BY groupname) AS Credit,SUM(debit) OVER(PARTITION BY groupname) AS debit,drcreffect,undergroup
    FROM @table) AS t0
join
    (SELECT row_number() as row_num, groupname,credit,debit, LAG(debit,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY groupname)-credit AS Total from (
        SELECT DISTINCT groupname,SUM(credit) OVER(PARTITION BY groupname) AS Credit,SUM(debit) OVER(PARTITION BY groupname) AS debit,drcreffect,undergroup
    FROM  @table1) AS t1
on  t0.row_num=t1.row_num
```

*PS: Seems a little odd to merge these seemingly unrelated querys. If I´d get such a request I´d question the motivation and see if ther is a better way to serve it. This screams Report Builder or Excel Template with inline querys*

Comment: union i  row wise merge table please see output result as i attached images

Comment: Your output example just shows the content of two selects next to each other with no apparent logic to connect them. What is the goal of getting this into one query?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211028/cross-entry-convert-based-on-2-entry-using-sql-server
please see my new question

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have the exact output as per your requirement because Column names are unique on each Table \ View and Hence you cannot have the same column name. But you may try this

```
;WITH T1
AS 
(
     SELECT 
          RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY groupname),
          groupname,
            credit,
            debit,
            LAG(debit, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY groupname)-credit AS Total
     FROM
    (
       SELECT DISTINCT
             groupname,
             SUM(credit) OVER(PARTITION BY groupname) AS Credit,
             SUM(debit) OVER(PARTITION BY groupname) AS debit,
             drcreffect,
             undergroup
       FROM @table
    )X
),T2
AS
(
     SELECT 
          RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY groupname),
          groupname,
            credit,
            debit,
            LAG(debit, 1, 0) OVER(ORDER BY groupname)-credit AS Total
     FROM
    (
       SELECT DISTINCT
             groupname,
             SUM(credit) OVER(PARTITION BY groupname) AS Credit,
             SUM(debit) OVER(PARTITION BY groupname) AS debit,
             drcreffect,
             undergroup
       FROM @table1
    ) X
),FNL
AS
(
    SELECT
       t1_groupname = T1.groupname,
       T1_Credit = T1.Credit,
       T1_debit = t1.debit,
       T1_Total = t1.Total,

       T2_groupname = T2.groupname,
       T2_Credit = T2.Credit,
       T2_debit = T2.debit,
       T2_Total = T2.Total

       FROM T1
          FULL JOIN T2
             ON T1.RN = T2.RN
)
SELECT 
    GroupName = t1_groupname,
    Credit = T1_Credit,
    Debit = T1_debit,
    Total = T1_Total,

    GroupName = T2_groupname,
    Credit = T2_Credit,
    Debit = T2_debit,
    Total = T2_Total

    FROM FNL

UNION

SELECT
    GroupName = 'Total',
    Credit = NULL,
    Debit = NULL,
    Total = SUM(T1_Total),

    GroupName = 'Total',
    Credit = NULL,
    Debit = NULL,
    Total = SUM(T2_Total)

    FROM FNL

UNION

SELECT
    GroupName = 'zGross Profit',
    Credit = NULL,
    Debit = NULL,
    Total = NULL,

    GroupName = 'Total',
    Credit = NULL,
    Debit = NULL,
    Total = SUM(T2_Total)-SUM(T1_Total)

    FROM FNL
```

Result

[image]

Comment: yes is one perfact open can you add sum of both total-total  and add last column

Comment: sartheesh some help for your query output
some minor issue please help me

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51077481/some-issue-for-group-by-sum-trading-report

Comment: hello sartheesh your answer is right but some minor issue can you update ,if you remove sales return rows to so total direct 5000 is total value but not display 5000 please help me

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210933/group-by-sum-based-on-under-group-in-sql-server
please check and please help me I have more Clarify for my quastion

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211028/cross-entry-convert-based-on-2-entry-using-sql-server please see my new question