# some issue for Group by sum Trading report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Some Minor Issue in my query can you help for issue.

This Is my Query

```
declare @table table (
    groupname varchar(50),
    credit numeric(18,2),
    debit numeric(18,2),
    undergroup varchar(50)
)

insert into @table
values ('Sales', 1210.00, 0.00, 'Sales'),
       ('Sales Return', 0.00, 0.00, 'Sales'),
       ('Closing Stock', 1400.00, 0.00, 'Closing Stock')

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY undergroup ) Cr_RN,
    groupname Cr_GroupName,
    ABS(Credit+Debit) Cr_Amount,
    ABS(LAG(Credit, 1, 0) OVER ( ORDER BY groupname ) -Debit ) AS Cr_Total
    FROM(
        SELECT
            GroupName GroupName,
            undergroup,
            SUM(ISNULL(Credit,0.00)) OVER (PARTITION BY groupname) AS Credit,
            SUM(ISNULL(Debit*-1,0.00)) OVER (PARTITION BY groupname) AS debit
        FROM @table
    ) X
```

My query Output

[image: My query Output]

Some Hint for output

[image: Some Hint for output]

And I want this type of output

[image: i want output like this]

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your questions, from the given example I'm not able to figure out any differences between your current and required outputs

Comment: please check and sorry for i have updated output images

Comment: Satheesh i have updated my output images please check my output result and requirement result

Comment: Alpesh, I didn't get your logic for that required output. Can you please explain about the last column Cr_Total?

Comment: cr_Total means every undergroup column name wise sum .Example
2 or 3 in undergroup is 'Sales' so end of Cr_GroupName add total sum

Comment: http://aramani.in/4.png please check rajesh
here 2 group sales and closing stock and every gropwise add sum is Cr_Total

Comment: If that is undergroup wise SUM then shouldn't the 2nd record be 1210 instead of 0?

Comment: yes second record  in cr_total display 1400 is wrong is display on first rows becasue of is not member of sales group is closing stock group

Comment: No, I was referring to 2nd record in your expected result, which is 0. Shouldn't be 1210 as second row comes under sales group?

Comment: hello rajesh no 1st column is under group closing group so cr_total 1400 and sales and sales return is sales group so cr_total 1210 to out cr_total 1210 can you share your contac detail so i call you so better understand its simple minor issue but i 2-3 day waste please help me

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210933/group-by-sum-based-on-under-group-in-sql-server
please check and please help me I have more Clarify for my quastion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alpesh, can you check this query please? This should give the expected results.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY undergroup ) Cr_RN,
    groupname Cr_GroupName,
    ABS(Credit+Debit) Cr_Amount,
    CASE WHEN LEAD(RID,1,0)OVER ( ORDER BY undergroup ) =RID+1 THEN 0 ELSE
    ABS(UG_Credit - UG_Debit ) END AS Cr_Total
    FROM(
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY undergroup ORDER BY undergroup ) RID,
            GroupName GroupName,
            undergroup,
            SUM(ISNULL(Credit,0.00)) OVER (PARTITION BY groupname) AS Credit,
            SUM(ISNULL(Debit*-1,0.00)) OVER (PARTITION BY groupname) AS debit,
            SUM(ISNULL(Credit,0.00)) OVER (PARTITION BY undergroup) AS UG_Credit,
            SUM(ISNULL(Debit*-1,0.00)) OVER (PARTITION BY undergroup) AS UG_Debit
        FROM @table
    ) X
```

Comment: ('Opening Balance', 500, 0.00, 'Dr', 'Master Group'),
       ('Opening Stock',   0.00, 200, 'Dr', 'Opening Stock'),
       ('Purchase',        0.00, 7800.00, 'Dr', 'Purchase'),
       ('Purchase Return', 2000.00, 0.00, 'Dr', 'Purchase'),
       ('Purchase Return', 3000.00, 0.00, 'Dr', 'Purchase'),
       ('Purchase Return', 3000.00, 0.00, 'Dr', 'Purchase') please add following data and check result everything is ok . but check purchase return 8000 every rows actually data 2000,3000,300 but value duplication value

Comment: Rajesh duplicate changes i have solve .but some groping please help me.http://aramani.in/1.png just add undergrop name as start up above

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/211028/cross-entry-convert-based-on-2-entry-using-sql-server  please see my new question